# Find hierarchical path between 2 nodes Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a node with Device label and there are such fields like - device_id, column1, column2, column3. I want to find a connection between node1 and node2 with known device_ids. These nodes are not connected explicitly by a specific attribute. They are connected by the other nodes in a few layers. So node1 is connected to other nodes by column1, retrieved nodes are connected to other nodes by column2, and the resulted nodes are connected to the node2 by column3.
How can I build a query to find such connections?
I tried to build such a query, but it returns nothing:

```
MATCH shortestPath((d:Device {device_id_id:1})-[:COLUMN1_DEVICES|COLUMN2_DEVICES|COLUMN3_DEVICES*1..4]->(d1:Device {device_id_id:2}))
RETURN d.device_id_id, d1.device_id_id
```

I think that the problem is with the last relation because it connects all the nodes with the equal column3 attributes, but it doesn't include empty values like "".
How can I take into consideration such a case?

Comment: Please, provide sample data for tests...

Comment: Replace `-[:COLUMN1_DEVICES|COLUMN2_DEVICES|COLUMN3_DEVICES*1..4]->` with `-[*..4]-` and see what that gives you. It looks like this path does not exist in your data. (Either requiring an unlisted relationship, or the relationship direction is wrong) The Cypher is correct from what little info we have, so this pattern probably isn't actually in your data.

Comment: Your query does not try to filter by relationship property values, so "empty values" should not be affecting the results.